# Как получить активность обращения к диску заданного процесса (Win API или WMI)

Tags: winapi, wmi, c++

Пишу приложение на С++ в том числе собирающее техническую информацию  по запущенным процессам (загрузку CPU, использование памяти, пользователь владелец процесса) и многое другое (все это уже реализовано).

Многие наверно видели в Task manager (windows 8) или в Мониторе ресурсов Windows можно наблюдать активность обращения к жесткому диску (чтение и запись в байтах). Мне нужно получать эту же информацию тоже.

К сожалению гугление и яндексение, положительных результатов пока не дало :(. Подскажите в какую сторону копать, может быть класс WMI или Win API структуру где можно прочитать эти данные.

Comment: Нашел вариант с GetProcessIoCounters. Там на выходе структура (интересуют поля содержащие слово Transfer). Эти счетчики считываю дважды, через определенный промежуток времени. Полученную дельту делим на паузу, получаю скорость обращения.

Answer (score 3):

Смотреть в сторону `HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA`. Почитайте например здесь  http://tripsin.narod.ru/articles/virtreg/virtregistry.htm